# How do I unstack the Morningstar effect?

Tags: borderlands-2

The [Morningstar](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Morningstar)'s voice (and critical effect) can transfer ("merge") with other weapons during the course of usual weapon manipulation (e.g., switching and reloading). The voice can be annoying, and if the Morningstar is switched to multiple times, the effects can stack multiple times, amplifying the voice.

How do I cancel this when it has already occurred, aside from quitting the game?

Comment: Just throwing out an idea, but have you tried dropping the gun and picking it back up?

Comment: Yes, but this does not work 100%. There's some sub-stipulation, but I can't say that I've pinpointed it yet or worked out a theory that holds. I can eventually answer this question on my own with science, but there's a benefit to asking it here.

Comment: My notes: "Does dropping the Morningstar cancel the voice infection? No. Having nothing equipped doesn't fix it either. It seems to be cancellable by dropping Morningstar before the ammo count comes up. Or drop-switching (dropping as one switches to a weapon) away from Morningstar." But these notes don't live up to my standards to answer with, and I guess I feel like if I do post them, I might as well test further.